# How do I get the POST result from a url endpoint? Django/Python

Tags: python, django, python-requests, endpoint

I have a system that sends a pin entry request to a client for payment processing. If client accepts payment and enters PIN, I get below results on my endpoint

I have tried to run the code below

```
response = requests.get('https://end9m3so3m5u9.x.pipedream.net/')

print(response.text)
print(response.status_code)
```

How do I access the ResultCode for further processing in my `views.py`? Please advice.

---

EDIT

---

Sorry if I wasn't clear. I am working with an API and I have an callback URL. Here's how it works:

1. Client makes a purchase
2. I inform the API of the Client's purchase and the price
3. API sends a PIN request notification to Client's phone
4. If client accepts transaction/declines transaction, API sends this (below) POST request/POST data (forgive me if the term is wrong, I'm new to this) to my endpoint url
   [image]
5. I need to obtain the ResponseCode below to know whether to proceed with the purchase/ decline it.

I have tried below code which doesn't work as i want:

```
response = requests.get('https://end9m3so3m5u9.x.pipedream.net/')

print(response.text)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())
print(response.content)
```

Please advice.

Comment: It's not clear what is now working for you, what error you see?

Comment: Not an errror. How to get the data that API posts to that URL?

Answer (score 0):

```
response = requests.get('https://end9m3so3m5u9.x.pipedream.net/')

print(response.json())
```

UPDATE:
See how it works in my python shell:
[image]

Comment: @RoyThande please see I uploaded image how it works in my python shell.

Comment: Nice @Sergey . I'm also getting the same. Issue is, once client accepts/declines, API will send some data to the url. That data sent is what i want to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `requests` libray?
If so, try this:

```py
response = requests.get('https://end9m3so3m5u9.x.pipedream.net/')

print(response.content)
```